# Apollonius's Problem: why PCC can be reduced to PPC

Tags: circles, tangent-line, geometric-construction

Here is the construction of the Apollonius's Problem PCC by deducing to PPC: https://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Geometry/GeoGebra/PCC.shtml But it is not mentioned how it works.

I'm trying to find the explanation, and I think it may be simplified as:

[image]

1. Draw two circles (*A*) and (*C*) tangent at *B*;
2. Draw a circle (*E*) tangent to (*C*) at *D* (here I make (*A*) and (*E*) intersected to avoid appearing 4 tangent lines in GeoGebra);
3. Draw two external tangent lines of (*A*) and (*E*) meeting at *H*, and *F* and *G* are two tangent points on one tangent line;
4. Draw a line passing through *H* and intersecting (*C*) at *J* and *K.

Prove that *FGKJ* are concyclic, which I haven't any idea yet.

Answer (score 1):

I just find a proof by calculating angles of isosceles triangles *BCD*, *BAF* and *DEG*.

[image]

Denote ∠*BAF* as $2\alpha$ and *DEG* as $2\beta$, then ∠*BCD* is $2\alpha+2\beta$ because *AF*||*EG*, then $\angle BFG=\alpha$ and $\angle BDG=\angle BDC+\angle CDG=\pi-\alpha$, then *BDGF* are concyclic.

Because *BDH* are collinear ([Monge & d'Alembert Three Circles Theorem II](http://gogeometry.com/javacar/Monge_2.htm)), we have: $$HB\cdot HD=HF\cdot HG=HJ\cdot HK$$ so *FGKJ* are concyclic.